# CBP Global Entry/SENTRI interviewing procedures for applicants with ASD?

Tags: usa, global-entry, sentri, autism, interview

My family have just received conditional approval for SENTRI, and now are looking at booking our interviews.

I am aware that children under 18 are interviewed with a parent present, however one of our kids is on the Autism Spectrum, and she probably won't cope well with an interview, even with one of us there with her.

Are there any guidelines or processes available for these interviews to allow for people with ASD?

My understanding is that all kids 14+ are interviewed, so she will be included in this as she's over 14.  I may be wrong on this understanding though.

Comment: People with autism are very different, I'd just have enjoyed it. Tell her she'll get an ice cream after the interview maybe (positive re-inforcement & [CBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy)). I'd say this question is better suited over at [Psychology.SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder thanks for your comment. I'm not after solutions for her, I'm after information about whether CBP have processes or guidelines about his they will handle a person with ASD.

Comment: I don't believe they have specific education. I did not find any mentions in FOIAed CBP manuals, but there's a lot of things that aren't public that way. However, IME (I'm autistic and got Global Entry on my own just after I turned 18), the interview is not really triggering. They are generally quite short, held in quiet areas, and didn't seem to insist on eye contact.

Comment: @GyðjaBjörnsdóttir Thanks for your comment.  I think the main concern I have is that my daughter tends to freak-out/panic if people talk to her or ask her things she doesn't immediately know the answer to.  If we knew we could go into the interview and say "she is on the autism spectrum" and know they'd respond a certain (hopefully positive) way, or treat her a bit more gently and with understanding, we (her parents) could help prepare her.  But with a bit more of an unknown it's more difficult